# How to use both the lexicalized and the dependency parser in the StanfordCoreNLP pipeline?

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

Suppose I have defined the following StanfordCoreNLP pipeline:

```
Properties props = new Properties();

props.put("language", "english");
props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, depparse");
props.put("depparse.model", "edu/stanford/nlp/models/parser/nndep/english_SD.gz");
props.put("parse.originalDependencies", true);

StanfordCoreNLP pipeline =  new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
```

Now, this code will give me the tokens, sentence splitter, POS tags, lemmas, NER and depdencency parse (the NN model). Now, I also want to have a lexicalized parse tree as well.

How can I put this information in the pipeline? Or maybe I have to do it otherwise? What is the optimal way to do this?

Comment: Try: `props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, depparse");` and see http://hujiaweibujidao.github.io/blog/2016/03/30/Stanford-NLP/

Comment: That works, thanks! Please write it down as a proper comment with code so I could accept it. Cheers!

Comment: I'm glad the answer helped =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of just `deparse`, add `parse` to the list of annotators:

```
props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, depparse");
```

For more details, see http://hujiaweibujidao.github.io/blog/2016/03/30/Stanford-NLP/